# Do C++ iterators need to be trivially copyable?

Tags: c++, iterator

I was thinking about creating an iterator to parse a binary format. Then I realized that in order to parse it properly, the iterator would need, from time to time, to stack up some context. Since a `std::stack` is not trivially copyable, I now have the following question:

Is it just a bad idea to have non trivially copyable iterators, or is it a requirement of *Iterator* as a concept?

Comment: Have a read of [C++ named requirements: LegacyIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Iterator) specifically the Requirements.

Comment: Nothing that I see [here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/iterator.requirements) requires copy/move operations to be trivial.

Comment: Iterators are required to be copy constructable and copy assignable.  Those requirements neither require nor prevent being trivially copyable.    Practically, it often works out that copying will be inexpensive by some measure (since iterators are often passed by value) but *how inexpensive* (or what measure) is not specified, so is a quality of implementation concern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, an [*Iterator*](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.iterators) does not have to be trivially copyable:

> A type `X` meets the *Cpp17Iterator* requirements if:
>
> - `X` meets the *Cpp17CopyConstructible*, *Cpp17CopyAssignable*, *Cpp17Swappable*, and *Cpp17Destructible* requirements ([utility.arg.requirements], [swappable.requirements]), and
> - `iterator_traits<X>​::​difference_type` is a signed integer type or void, and
> - the expressions in Table 86 are valid and have the indicated semantics.

- [[iterator.iterators] §2](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.iterators#2)

The C++20 iterator concepts also don't impose such a requirement.

##### Iterators are not trivially copyable, but should be lightweight

However, an iterator is generally supposed to be as lightweight as possible, and algorithms will assume that copying an iterator is a cheap operation. When you are designing iterators for your own container, you should make them as compact and cheap to copy as you can.

##### Example of how to make an iterator more lightweight

If you need an iterator to store a `std::stack`, something has probably gone wrong, but you might be able to eliminate it. For example, say your iterator performs depth-first traversal in a tree. If nodes in this graph don't have a pointer to their parent node, you need the iterator to keep a stack of parents so that it can go back up. However, if each node stores a pointer to its parent, the iterator doesn't need a parent stack. Also, we can look at the direction where we came from when going back up to a parent, and determine which child to go to next. This way, we don't need to track our own position within each stack frame.

If none of these things work, you could still traverse the data structure without any iterators, e.g. by writing a `for_each` function which accepts a function object that does something for every element.

In summary:

- keep more state in your data structure
- make traversal more intelligent (i.e. more logic in `operator++`)
- avoid use of iterators in some cases completely

Comment: Thanks, I am indeed thinking that maybe it is not the greatest idea to use iterators for parsing